# How to assign values for Activity variables in TestClasses

Tags: android, testing, robotium, android-testing

In my android project testing I am using `robotium` framework.

**What I need**

I have one boolean variable in my Activity based on this boolean value I do some operation.In my Activity `testing` class how can I set value to this boolean variable.Because I have to check if value set as `true/false`, corresponding operation is performing or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have many solutions:
1-If you do your network operation in an IntentService so you may broadcast an intent which has the value of your boolean variable when you finish your network operation.and create a broadcast receiver in your activity which listens to this intent

See this example 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html#tutorial_intentservice

2-If you do your network operation in a AsynckTask :
   A- Create an inner class of AsynckTask in your activity and in
      onPostExecute you can access the boolean variable of your activity

B-Make an observer which register to the asynckTask

Answer (score -1):

May you can give more clarification on what help you need ?

Where is the value of the boolean variable set?

Comment: In  Activity `onCreate()` method I have called a webservice which return `boolean(true/false)` value.If it returns `true` I will starting another activity .If it returns `false` I will show some alert. how can I test this activity?